# OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/User'. macOS Catalina

Tags: python, macos, macos-catalina, chmod, python-os

I was coding **sorter** for downloads folder. I'm getting this error, I tried to change permissions: 
`chmod: Unable to change file mode on Users: Operation not permitted`

```
import os

from_dir = os.path.dirname('/Users/user/Downloads/')
working_dir = os.walk(from_dir)
to_dir = os.path.dirname('/User/user/Downloads/New Folder/')


def move(folder):
    for roots, dirs, files in folder:
        for file in files:
            src_folder = from_dir + '/' + file
            to_folder = to_dir + '/' + file
            if not os.path.exists(to_dir):
                os.makedirs(to_dir)
            os.rename(src_folder, to_folder)


move(working_dir)
```

Maybe there is another way to write this code just without touching root folders?

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/beknazarnurbek/Documents/PycharmProjects/Move Files/move.py", line 19, in <module>
    move(working_dir)
  File "/Users/beknazarnurbek/Documents/PycharmProjects/Move Files/move.py", line 14, in move
    os.makedirs(to_dir)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 211, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 211, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 211, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 221, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/User'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error message is bit misleading. In this case, the problem is that there is no `/User` directory on macOS. The directory is named `/Users`.

In the following line

`to_dir = os.path.dirname('/User/user/Downloads/New Folder/')`

**User** should be **Users**

`to_dir = os.path.dirname('/Users/user/Downloads/New Folder/')`

What's happening is that `os.mkdirs()` is attempting to create a directory `User` in `/`. Which is not writable. Which is causing the error message.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the already existing answers:
You cannot write to the "input" directory as it is read-only.
So you will have to write to Another directory , like the one before the current one.

instead of writing to user/local/current
try to right to directory before current which is local in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just change '/static/' to 'static/' and 'media/' to 'media' in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this error by another circumstances - I had no space left on my hard disk. Solved by clearing some space.

Answer (score -1):

You have set writable permission to this folder. Just use in terminal chmod:

```
chmod -R 777 /absolute/path/to/your/folder
```

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably `chmod 755`) and if you have had world writable system files on a public-facing system, at the very least investigate whether it could have been breached and used as a pivot point for breaking into your organization’s network.

Answer (score -2):

Just removed `os.path.dirname` and it worked.

After I removed `os.path.dirname` it worked, but not how I was expecting. then trying to fix this, I messed up file system permission and just reinstalled OS. Now it works fine.

Comment: So then this is not really an answer to the question. It seems to me that the actual problem was that your file system was mounted read-only (as mentioned in the error message) and reinstalling the OS apparently solved your problem. BTW: reinstalling was overkill, you probably could have changed the mounting options to solve the problem without a complete reinstall.