# Not Creating New File If Empty Directory

Tags: python, file, flask, operating-system, discord.py

Alright, I'm creating a Python project of mine using my two favorite modules. Flask and discord. Now thus to say, I'm not the best, but I'm encountering a new error when trying to create a new file when directory is empty of said name. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
2.168.0.26 - - [18/Jun/2021 21:30:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
Trying to open Mewniverse's folder
File not found error raised
File not accessible. creating new.
[2021-06-18 21:30:42,559] ERROR in app: Exception on /favicon.ico [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "<string>", line 53, in hello_world
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/Mewniverse'
192.168.0.26 - - [18/Jun/2021 21:30:42] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Now here's my code(ignoring indentation and unfinished parts as it is heavily unfinished):

```
def hello_world(ID):
    print(f"Trying to open {ctx.author.name}'s folder")
    directory = f'/{ctx.author.name}'
    parent_dir = 'userFiles/templates'
    path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)

    if os.path.isfile(path):
        print ("File exist")
    else:
        print(f'File not found error raised')
        print("File not accessible. creating new.")
        f = open(path, "w")
        f.write("Now the file has more content!")
        f.close()
        print("Directory created and written in")

    return render_template(f'{ctx.author.name}.html')
        
    
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
            
        
await ctx.message.channel.send(f'Here you go {ctx.author.name}! Your site will be here: http://192.168.0.26:8080/{ctx.author.name}')
```

I've been stuck here for a few hours, so I'm hoping someone could help find a solution quickly. Thanks if possible.

Comment: Not sure if this is the solution but it looks like you can't create a new file because it's a read only directory. See if this post helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63085356/oserror-errno-30-read-only-file-system-user-macos-catalina

Comment: I read it over, and it seems that their problem was touching root folders, though mine doesn't involve any. It also had a command in there to change folder per motions, but it doesn't look like the (correct type of console code)(?) For my system. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Is this line `directory = f'/{ctx.author.name}'` a filename or directory name?

Comment: {ctx.author.name} is what, in discord.py, translates to the users name that used the command. So when I run $create, the bot will see what user sent said command, and basically fill that variable as {ctx.author.name}. so when I put it in there as the filename, its supposed to check to see if a file with the name of said user is created, and if not, create one. That being said, it does check for a file with the same name as my username when i run it. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: You may want to check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65524379/how-to-fix-read-only-file-system-error-python). See if what was suggested there helps.

Comment: That's not a bad suggestion at all, the thing with that is though, its not with Python at all. Their running shell scripts to edit a file extension. I can't exactly be using batch files in this code due to what I'm programming with. I need to be able to use pure Python to check, add, and edit files without this error. Thanks though!

Comment: How are you executing the script? Are you calling it directly, or via a service or something? Because when calling a script as a service, you need to give the **absolute** path to the files you want to work with. If your OS **thinks** that `path` is an absolute path, it will try to access something with very high privileges on the file tree, which might cause the problem.

Comment: Yea i think thats it! I never did add the absolute path so thank u!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from the comments:

> How are you executing the script? Are you calling it directly, or via a service or something? Because when calling a script as a service, **you need to give the absolute path to the files you want to work with**. If your OS thinks that path is an absolute path, it will try to access something with very high privileges on the file tree, which might cause the problem. – itzFlubby

Its 5 in the morning and i need sleep. So i just copied the answer down for you all to understand this is the fix. Thanks a lot <3